# How to fetch the result/row in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am learning mysql but I am not sure what is next going to be here in this code to get the matching row as result, how can I fetch that?

```
$stmt= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? and password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['user_name'],md5($_POST['user_pass']));
$stmt->execute();
```

I am sure this is a simple one for you, please help me out in learning things.

Comment: just a side note: md5 is not secure for password hashing in a production environment!

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Enabling errors isnt the soulution Im looking for :), but my point is, how do I print the result, so I can process it next level

Comment: Do you have anything stored in your db, far as a username/password goes?

Comment: yes, I have info in database

Comment: You've been given an "answer" below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at example #6 on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Here's the relevant bit, right after the bind_param() and the execute():

```
$out_id    = NULL;
$out_label = NULL;
if (!$stmt->bind_result($out_id, $out_label)) {
    echo "Binding output parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("id = %s (%s), label = %s (%s)\n", $out_id, gettype($out_id), $out_label, gettype($out_label));
}
```

Since I don't know what columns you are pulling in with your `SELECT *` I'll just leave the example as it stands.

You can also use `fetch_assoc()` which is probably a little easier to use and ends up being used a lot more commonly. Digging from the [same page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) on php.net we get this relevant portion from example #8 (actually I had to modify it somewhat - example #8 is doing some funky stuff with buffering):

```
if (!($res = $stmt->get_result())) {
    echo "Getting result set failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
$res->close();
```

Comment: many thanks, is there a way to grab all the columns of the matching row into an array? just like the general mysql_fetch_assoc in mysql?

Comment: I was already working on the edit for that - see the edited answer above.